# Call async method synchronously based on a condition

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I came across a scenario where a method needs to be called synchronously in case of 1 task which needs to be executed and send response back to the caller. Same method needs to be called asynchronously if there are more than one task to execute. How can I achieve this in Java?

```
public class Validator{

 @Async
 public String Validate(List<DataRecord> records){
 // Runs validation
 }

 public String processRecords(List<DataRecord> records){
     if(records.size <=5 ){
         // call method validate synchronously and return response
          return validate(records)
     }
     else{
         // Call method validate asynchronously
         validate(records)
         return "Records are being validated please visit the page after some time";
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Your question is lacking vital information. Please go ahead and update it with a more concrete example and/or possibly share what you have done already in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Create two methods, sync and async, and call common method which contains common logic from both the methods. Then according to your criteria, call any of the sync or async method.

Comment: Is the `@Async` annotation coming from `Spring`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the same method call, being your task in this case, in a `Runnable` submitted to an `Executor` for asynchronous execution, otherwise calling the method inline:

```
public class Validator {

    private final ExecutorService validatorExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public String validate(List<DataRecord> records){
        // Runs validation
    }

    public String processRecords(List<DataRecord> records){
        if(records.size <=5 ){
            // call method validate synchronously and return response
             return validate(records)
        } else {
            validatorExecutor.submit(() -> this.validate(records));
            return "Records are being validated please visit the page after some time";
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, you should bear in mind that is quite a trivial solution and does not:

- take any thread-safety consideration given your domain constraints
- use any underlying framework facilities